# How to submit same form continues times automatically?

Tags: jquery, ajax

What I want to achieve is get the `data` from success and submit the same form again with another url `data.url`

***Code HTML***

```
  <div class="user-show">
    <input type='text' name='user'>")
    <a href="#" id="fetch">Click here to fetch</a>
  </div>
```

***Code JS***

```
$(function() {
  $('a#fetch').bind('click', function() {
    $.getJSON($SCRIPT_ROOT + '/fetch', {
      name: $('input[name="username"]').val(),
    }, function(data) {
        if(data.user_name_list.next_url) {
          // Next url is here
        }
        $("#stop").html("<button>Stop</button>");
    });
    return false;
  });
});
```

Comment: _another url `data.url`_ define this. how you are getting it? do you have any array which holds the urls? or anything else other than this.

Comment: I have python server that can send array something like `{'next_url':'url', 'list_user':user_list}`

Comment: _submit the same form again_ and this one. As i see you are not submitting any form.

Comment: @Jai sorry... even i'm not using the form tag ... First I submit using `a` tag ...

Comment: _First I submit using a tag_ and then you want to call same ajax with new url which is available in the response.

Comment: @Jai I pasted the html.. And first in click of fetch.. this is time i want username and the next time my server response like if more than 50 user and it will return the another url for the next fetch ... You got it ?

Comment: @Roshni checkout the answer, you will get the idea how it should be done, and you can change it as per your need.

Answer (score 1):

refer [this](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/) link may help you

as per jquery source you can do like below.

```
$(function () {
    $('a#fetch').bind('click', function () {
        $.getJSON($SCRIPT_ROOT + '/fetch', {
            name: $('input[name="username"]').val(),
        }, function (data) {
            if (data.user_name_list.next_url) {
                // Next url is here
            }
            $("#stop").html("<button>Stop</button>");
        }).done(function (data) {
            $('#form').attr('action', data.url).submit();
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Oh.. i'll try this and I changed the original code for readability

Comment: I'm not using the form tag.. so can you change the code

Comment: @Rosini As per your question you say submit form? If not than please provide full code with explanation so I can provide you better solution.

Comment: @NikunjChotaliya that is why there is comment section, first you clarify the things and then you should post your answers. which is better not to having any downvotes.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
$(function() {
  $('a#fetch').bind('click', function() {
    var url = $SCRIPT_ROOT + '/fetch'; // declare var here.
    $.getJSON(url , {
      name: $('input[name="username"]').val(),
    }, function(data) {
        if(data.user_name_list.next_url) {
          // Next url is here
          url = data.user_name_list.next_url; // update the url here
          $('a#fetch').trigger('click'); // trigger click here.
        }
        $("#stop").html("<button>Stop</button>");
    });
    return false;
  });
});
```